# cannot install ffmpeg - all solutions do not work

Tags: apt, ffmpeg

I am using ubuntu 16.04. I am unable to install ffmpeg.

1) Aptitude does not work.

2) Restricted and Universe repositories have been enabled.

3) `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` outputs nothing.

4) `apt-mark showhold` outputs nothing

5) `sudo apt-get update` before running the above commands did not help

```
(base) h@cheemc52:~/opencv/build$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ffmpeg : Depends: libavcodec56 (>= 10:2.6.9) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavdevice56 (>= 10:2.6.9) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavfilter5 (>= 10:2.6.9) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavformat56 (>= 10:2.6.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried using aptitude but the solutions it provides does not work at all.
Solution 1.

```
(base) h@cheemc52:~$ sudo aptitude install ffmpeg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg libaacplus2{a} libass5{a} libavcodec56{ab} libavdevice56{a} libavfilter5{a} libavformat56{ab} libavresample2{a} libfaac0{a} libfdk-aac1{a} libpostproc53{a}
  libswresample1{a} libutvideo15{a} libvidstab1.0{a} libvo-aacenc0{a} libvo-amrwbenc0{a} libx264-146{a} libx265-51{a}
0 packages upgraded, 18 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,460 kB/8,543 kB of archives. After unpacking 23.1 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavformat56 : Depends: libgnutls-deb0-28 (>= 3.3.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

 libavcodec56 : Depends: libvpx1 (>= 1.3.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     ffmpeg [Not Installed]
2)     libavcodec56 [Not Installed]
3)     libavdevice56 [Not Installed]
4)     libavfilter5 [Not Installed]
5)     libavformat56 [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

(base) h@cheemc52:~$ ffmpeg
-bash: /usr/bin/ffmpeg: No such file or directory
```

Solution 2. All other solutions look similar to 2.

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Install the following packages:
1)      ffmpeg [7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (now, xenial-security, xenial-updates)]
2)      libavdevice-ffmpeg56 [7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (xenial-security, xenial-updates)]
3)      libavfilter-ffmpeg5 [7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (xenial-security, xenial-updates)]
4)      libbs2b0 [3.1.0+dfsg-2.2 (xenial)]
5)      libflite1 [2.0.0-release-1 (xenial)]
6)      libopenal-data [1:1.16.0-3 (now, xenial)]
7)      libopenal1 [1:1.16.0-3 (now, xenial)]
8)      libpostproc-ffmpeg53 [7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (xenial-security, xenial-updates)]

      Keep the following packages at their current version:
9)      libavcodec56 [Not Installed]
10)     libavdevice56 [Not Installed]
11)     libavfilter5 [Not Installed]
12)     libavformat56 [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg libass5{a} libavdevice-ffmpeg56{a} libavfilter-ffmpeg5{a} libbs2b0{a} libflite1{a} libopenal-data{a} libopenal1{a} libpostproc-ffmpeg53{a}
0 packages upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/15.1 MB of archives. After unpacking 33.0 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-ml2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-calib3d2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-legacy2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-contrib2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-core2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-features2d2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python-opencv' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-photo2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-objdetect2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-flann2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-video2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-imgproc2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-highgui2.4v5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 345098 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libopenal-data_1%3a1.16.0-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libopenal-data (1:1.16.0-3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libopenal1_1%3a1.16.0-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libopenal1:amd64 (1:1.16.0-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libass5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libass5_0.13.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libass5:amd64 (0.13.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbs2b0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libbs2b0_3.1.0+dfsg-2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbs2b0:amd64 (3.1.0+dfsg-2.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libflite1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libflite1_2.0.0-release-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libflite1:amd64 (2.0.0-release-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpostproc-ffmpeg53:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpostproc-ffmpeg53_7%3a2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpostproc-ffmpeg53:amd64 (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libavfilter-ffmpeg5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libavfilter-ffmpeg5_7%3a2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavfilter-ffmpeg5:amd64 (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libavdevice-ffmpeg56:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libavdevice-ffmpeg56_7%3a2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavdevice-ffmpeg56:amd64 (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../ffmpeg_7%3a2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ffmpeg (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libopenal-data (1:1.16.0-3) ...
Setting up libopenal1:amd64 (1:1.16.0-3) ...
Setting up libass5:amd64 (0.13.1-1) ...
Setting up libbs2b0:amd64 (3.1.0+dfsg-2.2) ...
Setting up libflite1:amd64 (2.0.0-release-1) ...
Setting up libpostproc-ffmpeg53:amd64 (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libavfilter-ffmpeg5:amd64 (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libavdevice-ffmpeg56:amd64 (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up ffmpeg (7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...

(base) haziq@cheemc52:~$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Where are you getting the package from?  The ffmpeg isn't a *xenial* package, and I note what look like debian packages in your pastes ... https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ffmpeg  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libgnutls&searchon=names

Comment: @guiverc thank you for responding. I am a retard that only knows how to write python code so I have no idea what you are saying. So what can I do ? How can I get ffmpeg installed ?

Comment: @guiverc do i need to get a xenial or debian ffmpeg package ?

Comment: If you follow the first link I provided, the xenial requires are found at https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ffmpeg which shows very clearly different requirements to your messages... ie. you've used non-Ubuntu/non-Xenial sources, and I cannot help without know what you've done to your system.

Comment: Debian packages are not the same as the Ubuntu ones (the format & structure is identical yes, but Ubuntu releases LTS on even years, Debian releases on odd years so they are **never** in sync with each other...  When I referred to Debian, I meant a .deb intended for Debian, and not a .deb intended for Ubuntu.  An `apt-cache policy ffmpeg` will show where you're getting the package from, and I bet it's not a Ubuntu 16.04 source

Comment: @guiverc thank you, are u saying that i might have destroyed my ubuntu installation ? and that i would need to reinstall it ?

Comment: Posting your `/etc/apt/sources.list` may help, no?

Comment: No; but the contamination of what I suspect of your sources (`/etc/apt/sources.list` & below) leads to dependency-hell type situations like what I suspect you have, meaning you need to manually remove the problem packages returning yourself back to a more standard system. I cannot see the results of `apt-cache policy ffmpeg` & other packages in your messages to see how bad your solution is.. Mixing sources for different releases/OSes increases skill required to fix this *dep-hell* like situations, we cannot see that detail unless provided (`sudo apt update`) etc.

Comment: @guiverc thank you very much for making it clear on the issue. I don't know which packages to remove though. Is there somewhere I can start or should I simply just reinstall ubuntu. The error messages make no sense to me at all.

Comment: @guiverc anyway thank you very much again. I have decided to reinstall ubuntu. At least I know the steps to do it. I will only end up wasting time if I try to fix something without having any idea on how to do so.

Comment: FYI: Easiest install is via 'something-else', select your existing partitions & don't format your partitions. That will cause installer to note your installed packages, install system, add back your additional packages (if available in available sources), then you're asked to reboot. Try the `apt-cache policy` for a package or two, and you'll see the versions your system detects, plus where they're from.. allowing you to detect sources you've added that take precedence (ie. `apt` type tools always picked highest version, even if that's not the 'best' for your system).

Comment: @Kong Why do you have "(base)" in front of command line prompt? Is it a chroot?